# Fractional Euler sums?

Tags: power-series

As we know, the classical linear double Euler sums is defined by
$${S_{p,q}} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{\zeta _n}\left( p \right)}}{{{n^q}}}} \;$$
where $p, q\  (q \ge 2)$ are positive integer,
$${\zeta _n}\left( p \right) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {\frac{1}{{{k^p}}}}. $$
Philippe Flajolet and Bruno Salvy
prove that for an odd weight $ m = p+q$, the linear Euler sums $S_{ p,q} $are reducible to Riemann zeta value. I have a question, if $p,\ q\ (q>1)$ are real number, then the fractional Euler sums  $S_{ p,q} $ can be evaluated? sunch as
$${S_{\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2}}} = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{\zeta _n}\left( {\frac{1}{2}} \right)}}{{{n^{\frac{3}{2}}}}}}  = ?.$$

Comment: Hmm, but $\frac 12$ and $\frac 32$ are not really real numbers, which is what I read in (and expect from) your question?

Comment: A more familiar notation for $~\zeta_n(p)~$ is $~H_n^{(p)},~$ which can be written as $~\zeta(p)~-~\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{(n+k)^p}.~$ For the special case $p=1$ we have $~\zeta_n(1)~=~H_n~=~n\cdot\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k~(n+k)}~=~\int_0^1\frac{~1-x^n}{1-x~}~dx.~$ All of this is spelled out rather explicitly in the *Wikipedia* article on [harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number), which can be found quite easily by way of a simple *Google* search.

Comment: In general, $$S_{p,~q} ~=~ \zeta(p)\zeta(q)-\frac1{\Gamma(p)}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log^{p-1}\big(1/x\big)\cdot\text{Li}_{q}(x)}{1-x}~dx.$$